# Automatonymous Quick Start does not compile

Tags: c#, masstransit

Please see the code below, which I took from the latest quick start tutorials:

```
//the messages
public class BasicRequest :
    CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get;set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
public class BasicResponse :
    CorrelatedBy<Guid>
{
    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

//the responder
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/message_responder");
            sbc.Subscribe(subs=>
            {
                subs.Handler<RequestMessage>(msg=> Bus.Instance.MessageContext<RequestMessage>().Respond(new BasiceResponse{Text = "RESP"+msg.Text}));
            });
        });
    }
}

//the requester
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Bus.Initialize(sbc =>
        {
            sbc.UseMsmq();
            sbc.VerifyMsmqConfiguration();
            sbc.UseMulticastSubscriptionClient();
            sbc.ReceiveFrom("msmq://localhost/message_requestor");
        });

        Bus.Instance.PublishRequest(new RequestMessage(), x =>
        {
            x.Handle<ResponseMessage>(message => Console.WriteLine(message.Text));
            x.SetTimeout(30.Seconds());
        });
    }
}
```

I took the code from here: https://automatonymous.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/request.html

The errors I get are:

1) Bus does not contain a definition for initialise

2) RequestMessage cannot be found

A lot of other webpages reference Bus.Initialise: https://automatonymous.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview/saga.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have found documentation that is beyond ancient. The fact you are using MSMQ clearly indicates it's a version of MassTransit that is many years out of being supported.

Documentation on using state machines with MassTransit:
http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/advanced/sagas/automatonymous.html

Samples that use state machines with MassTransit:
https://github.com/MassTransit/TheCoffeeShop

https://github.com/phatboyg/Demo-Registration

You'll have better luck working with the latest version of MassTransit.

Comment: I am trying to integrate a scatter gather pattern like this: https://dotnetcodr.com/2014/05/12/messaging-with-rabbitmq-and-net-c-part-5-headers-and-scattergather/ (but with Mass Transit).  Mass Transit does not appear to have a 'reply to' property.

Comment: Therefore the only way I can see this can be done (with Mass Transit) is for the sender to call each receiver individually using RPC like this: https://github.com/toddmeinershagen/Demo.ScatterGather/blob/master/src/Demo.ScatterGather/Demo.ScatterGather.Aggregator.Service/Controllers/PersonValidationsController.cs (see line 33 i.e. the sender knows all of the receivers).  The problem with this is that the sender has to know the receivers.  Have I understood this correctly?  Thank you.

Comment: You seem to be off course, you might get better help in the Gitter.Im chat room. But you can publish a message and have a regular consumer handle any responses to that event, you just need to keep track of them yourself. Using a saga doesn't seem to help in this case.

Comment: If you could post a link to any docs that explain how to setup a consumer to respond to responses for a specific event, then I would be grateful?  I will definitely check out Gitter.Im - thanks for that.

Comment: Could you have a look at my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516412/how-do-i-finalize-a-class-based-saga-so-that-it-is-deleted-from-the-sql-databas ? I have just realised that you are Phatboy of Gitter.